# WPF - TabControl Problem

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a TabControl with three Tab Items. When the user clicks on the second TabItem, I want to take him/her back to the first TabItem and set a certain TextBox to have the keyboard focus, if a certain circumstance is met. I'm having a heck of a time making this happen. I can easily set the current TabItem to the first one, but no matter what I try, I cannot get the keyboard focus to the TextBox I want. I've tried calling the Focus method on the TextBox and I've tried using the Keyboard.Focus() method. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the follwing code:

```
// Select here your tab
// ...
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate {       
    yourTextBox.Focus();        
 }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
```

Comment: @Hosea 146: If you start an operation through the Dispatcher with the argument ContextIdle, your operation will be executed after WPF has done all important work, generating template items, layouting, rendering, processing of inputs, ... Therefore your focus command can reach your textbox and no other operation can remove if afterwards. ContextIdle is a little strong, you can take also a value with a higher prio, but ContextIdle works for sure, that's why I use this value mostly for answering posts. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx